# How to create a shared repository in dumb server mode in Bazaar?

Tags: bazaar

How can I create a shared repository on a server if I only have access using `sftp://`?

As a workaround, I could create the shared repository locally and then I could copy it to the server.

In any case, can Bazaar use a remote shared repository in dumb server mode? Let's say I do this:

```
bzr init-repo /tmp/repo
rsync -a /tmp/repo server:/tmp/
cd /path/to/a/branch
bzr push sftp://server/tmp/repo/branch1
bzr push sftp://server/tmp/repo/branch2
```

Will the first `push` store its revisions in the shared repo, so that the second `push` will run very fast, since it doesn't need to store any new revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzr init-repo sftp://server/tmp/repo`

`rsync`ing it up should also work.

Yes if you push two branches into the same repository then they revisions will be stored in the repo and will not need to be pushed again ([unless you hit a re-pack](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/150099) which happens from time to time and that will cause it to be uploaded again).
So sftp can be slow with big branches. If you see that it is too slow, you can try out bzr+ssh:// which requires bazaar to be installed on the server. It may be possible to install bazaar in the user's home directory.

Comment: Nice, thanks! And yes, if you have shell access on a server then you can install Bazaar using `pip install --user bzr` for example.